# error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Encoding.GetBytes(string)'

Tags: c#, .net, console, runtime-error

I'm making a console app using .NET and when I ran the program I got this error.
`error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property Encoding.GetBytes(string)`.
It says the error came from this line:
`content.Add(Encoding.GetBytes("\n"+str));` (content is a List of type string and str is a string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`Encoding.GetBytes Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Encoding_GetBytes_System_String_) documentation:

> public virtual byte[] GetBytes (char[] chars);

It is not a static method, thus you are not allowed direct calling `Encoding.GetBytes` method.

Instead, you need to declare and assign an `Encoding` variable; only then use this variable to call `GetBytes` method.

```
var str = "Happy ending"; // Sample data
var encoding = Encoding.UTF8; // Set to your desired encoding
var bytes = encoding.GetBytes("\n"+str); // Return type: byte[]
```

For adding `bytes` into content of List, you may convert your `bytes` to desired format first.

**[Not `.ToString()`, it will returns result: "System.Byte[]"]**

```
var byteString = String.Join(" ", bytes);  // Format to your desired format
// Result of byteString: 10 72 97 112 112 121 32 101 110 100 105 110 103
content.Add(byteString);
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot that!